# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string() in .... on line 7

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
include "db.php";
```

extract($_POST);

```
$fname = str_replace("'","`",$fname); 
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($fname); <----

$lname = str_replace("'","`",$lname); 
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($lname);
```

Is about a registration form for a forum

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql\_escape\_string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614096/uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-escape-string)

Answer (score 1):

All mysql_* functions stoped working since PHP7.0, try using mysqli_* function like : mysqli_real_escape_string.

Don't forget to change your mysql_connect to mysqli_connect.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Lka’s message, mysqli_real_escape_string also takes the $db connection as the first parameter.